# Height of string when unicode text is in the string in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unicode

When I try to use this function having unicode text, it returns wrong height as its calculating height according the font size but emoticons are coming bigger and taking more height than without unicode.

> [text  sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(233.0f, 999.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

can real height be calculated having unicodes in the string?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CoreText framework.

You could try something like:

```
CTFrameSetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(myAttributedString);
CGSize size = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(frame setter, CFRangeMake(0, stringLength), NULL, CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight), NULL);
```

This should get the correct size for you. You can of course make maxHeight arbitrarily large to make sure that the string fits into the max size. Or you can pass a pointer to a CFRange as the last parameter and it will set it to the range of the string that it was able to fit into the max size that you passed it.

Hope this works for you :)